# DataBinder.Eval to two decimal places with dollar sign and no rounding

Tags: c#, data-binding

> How can i not round the Eval value and show value up to two decimal places with dollar sign?

I have tried `{0:C}` but it returns `68444.9976` to `$68445.00` and i want $68444.99.

```
<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Total")%>
```

Comment: try `{0:C2}` to format currency  to 2 decimal places

Comment: it returns 68445.00

Comment: It does but would return correct value for anything post .99, which is less than 5, like .9947, will become .99, but anything 5 or above is changed to .00, so its applying the floor and ceiling principle depending on whether you have 0-4 or 5-9 values in a decimal

Comment: Is there any way to have $68444.99 ?

Comment: Which means you never want ceiling value, it should always wrap to floor value, can you confirm

Comment: i don't want to apply any function round or floor, i just to display the amount how it is up to two decimal places with currency sign.

Answer (score 0):

You can write method like this in your *.aspx.cs file:

```
protected decimal MyCurrencyFormat(object item, string field)
{
    var value = Convert.ToDecimal(((DataRowView)item)[field]);
    var d1 = decimal.Truncate(value);
    var d2 = value - d1;
    if (d2 == 0) return value;

    var s1 = d2.ToString();
    var s2 = "";

    for (int i = 2; i < s1.Length; i++)
    {
        s2 += s1[i];
        if (s2.Length >= 2) break;
    }

    if (s2.Length == 1)
        return d1 + (decimal.Parse(s2) / 10);
    return d1 + (decimal.Parse(s2) / 100);
}
```

Then call it from *.aspx file:

```
<%#DataBinder.Eval(MyCurrencyFormat(Container.DataItem, "Total"))%>
```